# I'm ordering data. How to put first elements with a fixed class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm ordering some `div` with `jQuery/Javascript`: first for an attribute, than for another.
This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/j91zoaf1/):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="item" data-title="Marco" data-count="1">Marco (1)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Fabio" data-count="5">Fabio (5)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Edoardo" data-count="4">Edoardo (4)</div>
    <div class="item " data-title="Paolo" data-count="8">Paolo (8)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Luca" data-count="0">Luca (0)</div>
    <div class="item" data-title="Andrea" data-count="4">Andrea (4)</div>
</div>
```

```js
Order('#parent');
function Order(type) {
    var items = $(type + ' > .item');
    items.sort(function (a, b) {
        return +b.getAttribute('data-count') - +a.getAttribute('data-count') || a.getAttribute('data-title') > b.getAttribute('data-title');
    }).detach().appendTo($(type));
}
```

How you can see in the example, first is ordered by `data-count`, than by the `data-title` of the content.

What I'd like to do now is to put first the elements with the `selected` class on top; the other later.

But each "block" must be ordered as well by `data-count` and `data-title`. So in the example the result should be:

```
Fabio (5)
Edoardo (4)
Luca (0)
Paolo (8)
Andrea (4)
Marco (1)
```

how would you add a "order by class" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by comparing the results of `hasClass()`:

```
(+$(b).hasClass('selected') - +$(a).hasClass('selected'))
```

(`+` *boolean* is evaluated as `1` or `0` for `true` or `false`)

```js
Order('#parent');

function Order(type) {
  var items = $(type + ' > .item');
  items.sort(function(a, b) {

    return (+$(b).hasClass('selected') - +$(a).hasClass('selected'))  ||
      (+b.getAttribute('data-count') - +a.getAttribute('data-count')) || 
      (a.getAttribute('data-title').localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-title')));
  }).appendTo($(type));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    <div class="item" data-title="Marco" data-count="1">Marco (1)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Fabio" data-count="5">Fabio (5)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Edoardo" data-count="4">Edoardo (4)</div>
    <div class="item " data-title="Paolo" data-count="8">Paolo (8)</div>
    <div class="item selected" data-title="Luca" data-count="0">Luca (0)</div>
    <div class="item" data-title="Andrea" data-count="4">Andrea (4)</div>
</div>
```

Note the corrected string comparison (via `localeCompare()`), and that `detach()` isn't needed.

Comment: Good idea to use `.localeCompare()`! Somehow that's never occurred to me.

Comment: @Pointy I often forget about it, too. Somehow the name makes it feel like some obscure corner-case method, instead of The Thing You Sort On.

Answer (score 0):

To sort on a primary and a secondary key, the general approach is to return a `-1` or `+1` when you detect that the primary keys are different, and only move on to the secondary key when the primary keys are the same. *edit* In your case you have **three** keys: the presence/absence of "selected" in the "class", the count, and the title:

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    // test for the "selected" class
    var aSel = /\bselected\b/.test(a.className), bSel = /\bselected\b/.test(b.className);
    if (aSel && !bSel) return -1;
    if (bSel && !aSel) return 1;

    // test the counts
    var prim = +b.getAttribute('data-count') - +a.getAttribute('data-count');
    if (prim) return prim;

    // compare titles
    var aTitle = a.getAttribute('data-title'), bTitle = b.getAttribute('data-title');

    return aTitle < bTitle ? -1 :
           aTitle > bTitle ? 1 :
           0;
}).detach().appendTo($(type));
```

That way, if the count on one row is larger than the count on the next, there's no need to bother with the title so we don't even compare them. But if the counts are equal, then the title comparison determines the ordering.

That can be generalized to as many keys as you wanted of course.

Comment: This doesn't reply at all to my question :O

Comment: @markzzz oh OK you want elements that have the "selected" class first? I can update the answer.

Comment: @markzzz ok, updated.  Note that your existing comparison isn't really correct for the title comparison. To compare strings, you really have to explicitly check whether each is greater (or less) than the other. Otherwise, the sort can do weird things. *edit* or use `.localeCompare()` as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order('#parent');
function Order(type) {
var items = $(type + ' > .item');
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(b).hasClass('selected') || a.getAttribute('data-count').toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-count').toLowerCase()) 
           || a.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase());
}).detach().appendTo($(type));
```

}